# Asp.net core DbSet динамическое добавление Include

Tags: c#, asp.net

Всем привет! Продолжаю изучать asp.net core, и у меня есть просьба о помощи.
Есть у меня примитивный репозирторий:

```
public class Repository<TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    protected Context Db;
    protected DbSet<TEntity> DbSet;

    public Repository(Context context)
    {
        Db = context;
        DbSet = Db.Set<TEntity>();
    }


    public IEnumerable<TEntity> GetAll()
    {
        return DbSet.ToList();
    }
```

Меня интересует как я, могу динамически добавлять в DbSet.ToList(), еще например Include, что бы получалось так DbSet.Include(c=>c.Table).ToList() ? То есть что бы я в сервисе мог вызвать вот так _localizationRepository.GetAll() и вот так _localizationRepository.Include(c=>c.Table).GetAll(), как это правильно организовать. Спасибо

Comment: попробуйте сделать еще один метод как [тут](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5376637/3373603)

Comment: Отлично, то что нужно, спасибо!!!